# C++/WinRT: How to create a DataTemplate with binding in code?

Tags: datatemplate, c++-winrt

I need to implement a C++/WinRT application completely without using XAML code. However, I am stuck with the DataTemplate. The following XAML code is to be converted into C++:

```
<ComboBox> 
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyComboBoxItemUC Item="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this in a view or a template? Is your VM binding correctly?

Comment: For example, the ComboBox is part of a UserControl. However, this is not really important, as the solution cannot presuppose a parent. The binding is correct. The code has been tested.

Comment: In C++/WinRT, you can create a `DataTemplate` from code by using the [XamlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader?view=winrt-22621) class to load XAML from `hstring`. ` hstring xaml = LR"(your xaml code)" ; DataTemplate template = unbox_value<DataTemplate>(XamlReader::Load(xaml));` Can this meet your needs?

Comment: As an auxiliary solution for the present sample code, this might be sufficient. However, if the DataTemplate has a more complex structure, extensive XAML code will be created. This is exactly what I want to avoid. 
Apart from that: In order to get the example to work using XamlReader, the "Local" namespace must be resolved. Let's assume that the definition in the surrounding view is 'xmlns:local="using:my_app"'. What does the code look like then?